# variation partitioning with a GAMM model including an auto-correlation structure in R

Tags: r, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, partitioning

I would like to undertake variation partitioning in a GAM framework in R, as described here: https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/variance-explained-by-each-term-in-a-GAM-td836513.html

However, my gam model has auto-correlated residuals, which leads to over-fitted smooth terms. So I fitted a gamm model with an appropriate correlation structure, and checked the residuals were no longer auto-correlated, but I am not entirely sure how to undertake variation partitioning with such a model.

I had a go at extracting the smooth terms from the gamm model, refitting my gam model with those smooth terms - hoping this would alleviate the over-fitting issue -, and from there following Simon Wood's instructions in the post above. Is this the correct approach?

If it is, here's a second question: I realised the smooth terms of the gamm and of the refitted gam are not exactly the same, and I don't understand why.

Below is a reproducible example (I know the gamm1 model is rubbish and residuals are still auto-correlated - this is just an example. In my actual gamm model residuals are no longer auto-correlated):

```
library(mgcv)
dat<-airquality
dat$d<-c(1:nrow(dat))

# initial gam model
gam1<-gam(Ozone~s(Solar.R)+s(Wind), data=dat, method="ML")

# gamm model with corAR1 structure
gamm1<-gamm(Ozone~s(Solar.R)+s(Wind), data=dat, method="ML", correlation=corAR1(form=~d))

# extract smooth terms from gamm
sp.gamm1<-gamm1$gam$sp

# refit gam with these smooth terms
gam2<-gam(Ozone~s(Solar.R)+s(Wind), sp=sp.gamm1, data=dat, method="ML")

# then follow steps described by Simon Woods

# BUT:
plot(gamm1$gam)
```

Second plot:

[image]

```
plot(gam2)
```

Second plot:

[image]

I was expecting both plots to be identical, they are not...

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible for `gamm()` models as as far as I know there isn't a mechanism in `lme()` to fix the random effects variance(s), which is what fixing the smoothness parameters is doing. When you set `sp`, it's being passed via the `...` method but that has the side effect of just leading to `lme()` silently ignoring this argument.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: Thanks Gavin. If the `sp` argument is ignored, then why are `plot(gam1)` and `plot(gam2)` not strictly identical either?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson. I probably misunderstood your answer: you're actually saying it is not possible to do variation partitioning using `gamm`, that's noted. As a workaround, I was hoping to find the correct smoothness parameters using `gamm`, and then use these parameters to fix smoothness parameters in `gam`, by setting `sp` in the `gam(Ozone~s(Solar.R)+s(Wind), sp=sp.gamm1,...)` call, as described in the post I referred to. This has an effect since `plot(gam1)` and `plot(gam2)` are not strictly identical - but I still don't understand why `plot(gamm1$gam)` and `plot(gam2)` are not identical.

Comment: The difference must be due to the different algorithms being used by `gamm` and `gam`, which are still having to estimate parameters for the smooths conditional upon the given smoothness parameters